# What is the best shape of these 4 to make a parabolic microphone?

Tags: acoustics

I'm building a parabolic Microphone
I have found 4 inexpensive reflectors (actually repurposed squirrel baffles).
Which in you opinion would be the best? They are all slightly different shape.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

why not just get hold of a scrap cable tv mini-dish? They have just the right shape, and you can immediately see just where the focus point is for mounting the microphone element.

Comment: I have one, I think off axis external sounds are vibrating the metal and it is re-transmitting that off axis sound to the microphone. I have had the suggestion to back the dish with the sticky tar tape or flashing sealer. And I may try that.